# Chinese characters appear in different encoding after writing to webpage using cURL

Tags: python, curl, encoding, utf-8

I am using cURL to inject Chinese characters to my webpage after URL encoding as follows:

```
rep_keywords = urllib.quote(unicode(keywords).encode("utf-8"))
subprocess.Popen(['curl','-u', 'admin:admin','-X','POST','--data',"metacustom="+rep_keywords, ""+path])
```

The characters get encoded like this:

```
%E7%BC%96%E8%AF%91%E9%94%99%E8%AF%AF%EF%BC%
```

However, on the webpage, they appear like this:

```
æ ¼æ‹‰
```

Every post I read on this issue mentions UTF-8 encoding should do the trick to display Chinese characters, but this doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I don't think this is a Python question.  It might be related to [fonts](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/faq/chinese-web-site-fonts-and-character-sets.htm)

Comment: Check the encoding of your webpage. That could be valid UTF-8 being interpreted and displayed as if it were some other encoding.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
My webpage's encoding is UTF-8

Comment: The encoding seems to be Windows-1252. Any idea why it is translating to that encoding, even when UTF-8 is specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of charset in my POST request made the difference. Also, used '-F' (to specify multipart POST data in a form) instead of '-d'. Here is my piece of code:

```
subprocess.Popen(['curl','-u', 'admin:admin','-F','_charset_=UTF8','-F',"metacustom="+rep_keywords, ""+path])
```

Before the post request, encode the unicode strings to utf-8:

```
rep_keywords = keywords.encode('utf8')
```